# Questions about asymmetric encryption

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am designing a database that will contain sensitive data.

I would like to encrypt the data so that no one can read or alter it, except my server-side application.

I saw this guide online: https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/sql-server-best-practices-using-asymmetric-keys-to-implement-column-encryption_594390

But I don't understand where is the security?

If an attacker manages to run `DECRYPTBYASYMKEY` am I not back to the square?

Comment: @marc_s isn't private key stored on SQL server? Are they for on user?

Comment: The actual key can be protected with user permissions. If someone has `sa` or Windows Administrator then it's game over, but it's game over for other, bigger reasons then.

Comment: so what's the point of encrypting data if I'm ensuring nobody can access It?

Comment: If you use user permissions correctly and don't post the key on Facebook then nobody can access it who is not allowed

Comment: @Charlieface ok but what's the point of encrypting data if I'm ensuring nobody can access it? Is it worth it?

Comment: Huh? No idea why you want to. That's for you to decide whether the overhead is worth it for protecting the data. Be aware that Column Level Encryption is hackable, and Always Encrypted is a much better option, but can be more complex to program on the client side. **At the very least** enabling Forced SSL/TLS is a no brainer

Comment: The entire point of encryption is based on keeping the key in a different place than the data. Usually, you keep the key in the application server (and the data in the database server). The data is on a big cheap storage (HDD), the key can be in a smaller, more expensive storage (TPM chip, for example). To protect the data stored in the TPM chip, you use another key, which is stored somewhere else (the smallest, most expensive storage is the human brain).